# ListView is not scrolling with grouping

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms

I simply changed my `ListView` to use grouping, but now I can't use `ScrollTo` anymore.

I have create a simple app, so you can see the problem.

The XAML-page looks like (I am not using XAML in my app at the moment, but I will in an upcoming version).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ScrollListExample"
   x:Class="ScrollListExample.ProjectPage">

   <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
         <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <ListView x:Name="ProjectsListView" HasUnevenRows="True" IsGroupingEnabled="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}">
         <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <ViewCell>
                  <Label Text="{Binding Path=Key}" />
               </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
         </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
         <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <ViewCell>
                  <Grid>
                     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" Text="{Binding Path=ProjectName}" />
                     <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=ProjectReference, StringFormat='Sag: {0}'}" />
                     <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Path=CustomerName}" />
                     <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Path=FullAddress}" />
                     <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=StartTime}" />
                  </Grid>
               </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
         </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
   </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

And the code-behind file for the example looks like this

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ProjectPage : ContentPage
{
   public ProjectPage()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      BindingContext = new ProjectsViewModel();
   }

   protected override void OnAppearing()
   {
      base.OnAppearing();

      Acr.UserDialogs.UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading();

      var projects = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<ProjectDto>>("[{\"ProjectName\":\"Test sag\",\"ProjectReference\":\"10072\",\"CustomerName\":\"Test firma\",\"FullAddress\":\"Testvej 3\",\"StartDate\":\"2017-02-02T00:00:00\",\"StartTime\":\"\"},{\"ProjectName\":\"aaa\",\"ProjectReference\":\"10077\",\"CustomerName\":\"Test firma\",\"FullAddress\":\"Testvej 12\",\"StartDate\":\"2017-02-08T00:00:00\",\"StartTime\":\"\"},{\"ProjectName\":\"Test\",\"ProjectReference\":\"10082\",\"CustomerName\":\"Test firma\",\"FullAddress\":\"Testvej 50\",\"StartDate\":\"2017-02-16T00:00:00\",\"StartTime\":\"\"},{\"ProjectName\":\"Test\",\"ProjectReference\":\"10085\",\"CustomerName\":\"Testvej boligselskab\",\"FullAddress\":\"Testvej 14\",\"StartDate\":\"2017-02-24T00:00:00\",\"StartTime\":\"\"},{\"ProjectName\":\"Test\",\"ProjectReference\":\"10086\",\"CustomerName\":\"Testing\",\"FullAddress\":\"Testevej 14\",\"StartDate\":\"2017-02-27T00:00:00\",\"StartTime\":\"\"},{\"ProjectName\":\"Test1\",\"ProjectReference\":\"10087\",\"CustomerName\":\"Plejecenter testlyst\",\"FullAddress\":\"Testlystvej 11\",\"StartDate\":\"2017-02-27T00:00:00\",\"StartTime\":\"\"},{\"ProjectName\":\"Test2\",\"ProjectReference\":\"10088\",\"CustomerName\":\"Charlie\",\"FullAddress\":\"Testvej 50\",\"StartDate\":\"2017-02-27T00:00:00\",\"StartTime\":\"\"},{\"ProjectName\":\"Test\",\"ProjectReference\":\"10089\",\"CustomerName\":\"Standard Debitor\",\"FullAddress\":\"[Mangler]\",\"StartDate\":\"2017-03-16T00:00:00\",\"StartTime\":\"\"},{\"ProjectName\":\"Test\",\"ProjectReference\":\"10090\",\"CustomerName\":\"Standard Debitor\",\"FullAddress\":\"[Mangler]\",\"StartDate\":\"2017-03-16T00:00:00\",\"StartTime\":\"\"},{\"ProjectName\":\"Test\",\"ProjectReference\":\"10091\",\"CustomerName\":\"Standard Debitor\",\"FullAddress\":\"[Mangler]\",\"StartDate\":\"2017-03-16T00:00:00\",\"StartTime\":\"\"},{\"ProjectName\":\"Test\",\"ProjectReference\":\"10092\",\"CustomerName\":\"Tester\",\"FullAddress\":\"Testvej 11\",\"StartDate\":\"2017-03-16T00:00:00\",\"StartTime\":\"\"},{\"ProjectName\":\"Test\",\"ProjectReference\":\"10093\",\"CustomerName\":\"Plejehjemmet test\",\"FullAddress\":\"Testvej 90\",\"StartDate\":\"2017-03-16T00:00:00\",\"StartTime\":\"\"},{\"ProjectName\":\"Test\",\"ProjectReference\":\"10094\",\"CustomerName\":\"Plejehjemmet test\",\"FullAddress\":\"Testvej 90\",\"StartDate\":\"2017-03-16T00:00:00\",\"StartTime\":\"\"}]");

      var viewModel = BindingContext as ProjectsViewModel;
      if (viewModel != null)
         viewModel.OriginalProjects = projects;

      Acr.UserDialogs.UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Loading");

      Task.Delay(5000).ContinueWith((x) =>
      {
          Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(Acr.UserDialogs.UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading);

         Search();
      });
   }

   private void Search(string inputVal = null)
   {
      var viewModel = BindingContext as ProjectsViewModel;

      if (viewModel != null)
      {
         var projects = viewModel.OriginalProjects.Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputVal) ? p.ProjectName.Contains(inputVal) : true);

         var orderedProjects = projects.OrderBy(p => p.StartDate);

         Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
         {
            foreach (ProjectDto project in orderedProjects)
            {
               var coll = viewModel.Projects.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Key == project.StartDate);

               if (coll == null)
                  viewModel.Projects.Add(coll = new ObservableCollectionWithDateKey { Key = project.StartDate });

               coll.Add(project);
            }

            var group = viewModel.Projects.LastOrDefault();
            if (group != null)
               ProjectsListView.ScrollTo(group.First(), group.Key, ScrollToPosition.Start, false);
         });
      }
   }
}

class ProjectsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private ObservableCollection<ObservableCollectionWithDateKey> _projects;

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   public IEnumerable<ProjectDto> OriginalProjects { get; set; }

   public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollectionWithDateKey> Projects
   {
      get { return _projects; }
      set
      {
         _projects = value;
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Projects)));
      }
   }

   public ProjectsViewModel()
   {
      Projects = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollectionWithDateKey>();
   }
}

public class ProjectDto : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public string ProjectName { get; set; }
   public string ProjectReference { get; set; }
   public string CustomerName { get; set; }
   public string FullAddress { get; set; }
   public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
   public string StartTime { get; set; }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

class ObservableCollectionWithDateKey : ObservableCollection<ProjectDto>
{
   public DateTime Key { get; set; }
}
```

I use `Task.Delay(5000)` to simulate a response from the server, but I do not think, it matters.

**UPDATE**

I figured out, the problem was in my `ScrollTo`-call, where `ScrollTo(group.First(), group.Key, ScrollToPosition.Start, false);` was called with the Key instead of just the group.

If you create the grouping first (without adding it to the ViewModel), you have to find the correct model in the ViewModel afterwards. As it otherwise does not find the correct ObservableCollection

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but you should scroll to your "physical" item. I didn't do it with grouping, but here is how my code looks like:

 `BranchesAndTagsList.ScrollTo(BranchesAndTagsList.ItemsSource.Cast<object>().ToList()[_index], ScrollToPosition.Center, true);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tested your code and reproduced your issue. The problem is you have passed the wrong parameter to [`ScrollTo`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.ListView.ScrollTo/p/System.Object/System.Object/Xamarin.Forms.ScrollToPosition/System.Boolean/) method.

```
ProjectsListView.ScrollTo(group.First(), group.Key, ScrollToPosition.Start, false);
```

The `group` parameter of `ScrollTo` method is the group from your `ListView.ItemsSource`. But your passed a `group.Key`. So the method will not be excited as expect. Please modify the code like following.

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
 {
     foreach (ProjectDto project in orderedProjects)
     {
         var coll = viewModel.Projects.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Key == project.StartDate);

         if (coll == null)
             viewModel.Projects.Add(coll = new ObservableCollectionWithDateKey { Key = project.StartDate });

         coll.Add(project);
     }
 var group = viewModel.Projects.Last();
 if (group != null)
     ProjectsListView.ScrollTo(group.First(), group, ScrollToPosition.Start, false);
});
```

Comment: Somehow it works in my sample but not in my real app :(

Comment: Have you tried to pass the `group` to `ScrollTo` method  in your real app?

Comment: Yes, but I figured out, I have to look the group up in the ViewModel before scrolling to it. 
If I do not set a `Task.Delay(200)` for UWP, I get a UnhandledException. I tried wrapping the `ScrollTo` in a try-catch, but I could not catch it in there :( 
Do you have any idea of, what I can do then?

Comment: I can't get your point by your segment description. I recommend  you could create a new thread to clarify your requirement.