# ListView ScrollTo without delay on UWP

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms

I have created a simple `ListView` as I showed on my [ListView is not scrolling with grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42979878/listview-is-not-scrolling-with-grouping) question.

My problem is, that on UWP, I need to insert a `await Task.Delay(1500)` on Windows Phone, and about `200ms` on Windows Desktop. 
I am not filling the `ListView` with a lot of data, so I also want to know, what happen when the user runs it, as they can have a lot of data.

But why do I need it, cause to me it seems like a buggy code?

The Exception I am getting without `Task.Delay` is `Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.`

The message is

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementRenderer`2.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementRenderer`2.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Plat
```

How can I fix this error/buggy code?

**UPDATE**
If I set `HasUnevenRows = false` it does not crash, but it just scrolls to the incorrect `ViewCell`. But I need to use `HasUnevenRows = true`.
The same problem is occuring if I set `HasUnevenRows = false` and a RowHeight.

Comment: I think it might have to do with wrapping the `ListView` in a `Grid`. Have a look at this [bug report](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52349). While a `ScrollView` is different from a `Grid` of course, maybe it causes problems in this particular scenario. You could at least try to get it out of the `Grid` to verify it works?

Comment: No, it still crashes :(

Comment: I have created a  [sample application](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/ListViewScrollingTest.git)  for reproducing your issue([ListView is not scrolling with grouping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42979878/listview-is-not-scrolling-with-grouping)). It also used `Task.Delay()`  to simulate a response from the server, but  there is no exception thrown out.

Comment: As I can see it, the only difference is, that I am setting `IsPullToRefreshEnabled = true` and of course a Command and IsRefreshing property for it. And that I am using C# all the way instead of XAML.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was similar to yours, where a `Task.Delay()` made the scrolling work on iOS. The reason was threading, where the scrolling was not in sync with other "tasks". After going from

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
   listView.ScrollTo(defaultItem, ScrollToPosition.Center, true);
});
```

to

```
listView.ScrollTo(defaultItem, ScrollToPosition.Center, true);
```

I didn't need `Task.Delay()` anymore and the scrolling does work now. Though I never got your exception.